# Questions about solid state drives?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, ssd, ext3, ext4

1. How to tell if a hard drive is solid
   state drive?  For example:

   - For one laptop, its hard drive is    244GB Western Digital WDC
     WD2500BEVS-08VAT2 (SATA)
   - For another, its hard drive is 98GB    Seagate ST9100822A (ATA).
2. can Ext3 or Ext4 be used for solid
   state drives? Can journaling be used for solid state drives?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Easiest thing to do is Google the drives.  Both of these are normal hard drives. (Easiest way to eyeball is to notice that they have RPMs listed!) Generally a solid state drive is going to OBVIOUSLY be a solid state drive - manufacturers want to advertise this fact.  (They're also not usually coming from traditional hard drive manufacturers like WD and Seagate - most SSDs are made by memory manufacturers.)

2) For all intents and purposes, at least until you get to issues like TRIM, the technology of the physical media doesn't matter, just the interface.  A SATA drive is a SATA drive and a filesystem is a filesystem.  I have heard that journaling is a poor choice for an SSD simply due to the write load, but in the absence of hard numbers I suspect this is simply fearmongering.